# Feed post functionality using MultiAutoCompleteTextview Android

Tags: android, facebook, tags, multiautocompletetextview

I am trying to build a social **`networking application`** which is having feed post functionality same like **Facebook** or **Instagram**.

This includes **tagging friends** and adding **hash tags**. I have achieved the functionality to tag a friend using *`MultiAutoCompleteTextView`*. It works in the following way:

**1)** When I type **@** then it populates the list of my friends.

**2)** When I click any particular friend it got added in the feed description area.

But the problem is that suppose I tag a friend in my post then again he would not be listed in the list of *`MultiAutoCompleteTextView`* drop down so that one friend can be tagged once.

Suppose i have removed that tagged friend from the description then only it would be visible again in the *`MultiAutoCompleteTextView`* drop down.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all where is the user-list source coming from? If the source coming from your own server you could easily sending the `userID` to the server to tell your database to not query specific `userID`. This approach is very good in the case if you using `LIMIT`, if your user try to tag all the people with starting name John then if your record return only 15 record once your user will not getting any data.

Second method will be just using a `ArrayList<>` to store the user which you already click. Then you could check something like this

```
if(!arrayList.contains("key")){
    result.add("key");
}
```

Which `arrayList` is where you store your value of user. If it doesn't contain in that `arrayList` mean it doesn't selected by the user just go ahead add it into your array. It is just suggestion you need to think how to integrate to your app.

Here is the thing you could mention repeatly with same user in instagram or facebook. If it doesn't contain in the drop down list your user still can typing in the same character to mention that user again so if you worry about notification or something it is better to check for that as well. social application is very hard took me year to built a good one.

Comment: But if i delete any tagged friend from description, then how would i notify the server that which friend is deleted. So that server can send that friend in query response.

Comment: I think the best way for you is to store thing inside an arrayList. When you click the drop down list add it into arrayList, remove just remove from arrayList. Then you could loop through every value inside your arrayList send it to the server.

Comment: How to get the removed tagged friend from MultiAutoCompleteTextview. Like if i tag more than one friend in description and i remove any friend randomly. So, how to get that removed friend name? So that i can send that name to server.

Comment: Hmm.. I don't think multiAutoCompleteTextView have this kind of functionality. You have to written your own code with your own logic in the textWatcher

Answer (score 0):

The ListView All automatically populate when you type @.
For this, Use Custom AutoComplete TextView